# Need help understanding Conway's Game of Life

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to write code for Conway's Game of Life to determine the immediate next pattern for a given pattern of cells, but I'm not sure whether I really understand the steps. So for example consider the below toad pattern. The cells marked x are alive and those marked - are dead.

```
-XXX
XXX-
```

The above should transpose into the following

```
--x-
x--x
x--x
-x--
```

The rules as we know are:

1. A live cell with less than 2 or more than 3 neighbours dies
2. A live cell with exactly 2 or 3 neighbours survives
3. A dead cell with exactly 3 neighbours comes to life.

So, the first cell in the input c[0,0] is - and it has 3 live neigbours (one horizontally,vertically and diagonally each), so it should be alive in the output, but it's not. Can someone please explain?

Comment: What do you mean `it should be alive in the output, but its not.`? Do you have a bug in your program or you don't understand how it can work at all?

Comment: perhaps a bug in your code?  why does the first state in your post have 2 rows while the second state has 4 rows?  you haven't provided any code so how is anyone to know whats wrong with your code? :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter and Nerdtron.I havent started coding. Im, just trying to understand, how the above transposition takes place. The input has two rows but output 4,and im not sure how that can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle two rows in your output are the ones that correspond to the two rows in your input. The upper left cell in the input corresponds to the second row extreme left in the output, and as you can see, it's alive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ernest. I understand your point But if the middle two rows of the ouput are corresponding to the two rows of my input then how are the uppermost and lowermost rows being generated ?

Comment: Specifically, why does the output have 4 rows when the input has only two ?

Comment: It is implied that the eight cells in the middle are embedded in an infinite field of dead cells; you always have to do the computation on such an implicit infinite field. In practice, since the "speed of light" in Life is just one cell per generation, it's a reasonable approximation to just keep a border of one extra (not displayed) cell all around your field. You won't get the exactly correct result this way, but it's better than nothing. The larger field you use, and the more non-displayed rows you include, the more accurate your results.

Comment: OK, i got it. It seems if a row has n cells the output has to be generated for n x n grid. This makes sense now. Thank You :)

Comment: No, at least (n+1) x (n+1) to get 100% accurate results in the next generation. The one after that may be incorrect unless your field is (n+2) x (n+2), though -- and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is alive in the output. It's right here:

--x-
**x**--x
x--x
-x--

The `x` in the first row is *above* the first row in the first output. The rules of Life assume an unbounded plane. If you want to call the top row of the first output `0`, you can, but then the top row of the second output is `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is. Your 2-line long input is the middle part of your 4-line output. I think when you look at it now you'll understand everything.

Have you looked at least at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)?